# When uploading anything over 1MB php.ini does not allow even when changed post_max_size, upload_max_filesize and memory_limit AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file, size, uploading

I am having trouble uploading anything over 1MB on my site I have tried changing `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` and `memory_limit` to all fit the size ratio of which my files that are being uploading in the php.ini file located at `/etc/php.ini` and restarting the server using `service httpd restart` but it still gives me this error

```
Error:Unable to open FOLDER_UPLOADING_TO/FILE_THAT_I_AM_UPLOADING using mode r:
  fopen(FOLDER_UPLOADING_TO/FILE_THAT_I_AM_UPLOADING): failed to open stream: 
  No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a permission issues with function `move_uploaded_file`

Are you sure that the target directory has write permissions for world?
i.e. the third number in permission representation? 
The files uploaded by php are owned by and comes under the group www-data

You can change the ownership by

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data folder // change owner
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data folder // change group and owner
```

folder is where you are saving the uploaded files...

Comment: Thanks for the answer when pasting this code into my terminal it tells me that chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:www-data’ is there anyway I could get around this? 

Comment: try `apache` instead of `www-data`

Comment: thanks answer it did successfully  change the owner and the group of my my uploads folder to apache but on my website when trying to upload a file it still gives me the same error 

Error:Unable to open FOLDER_UPLOADING_TO/FILE_THAT_I_AM_UPLOADING using mode r:
  fopen(FOLDER_UPLOADING_TO/FILE_THAT_I_AM_UPLOADING): failed to open stream: 
  No such file or directory